# Submitting a p:fileupload with the rest of a form

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious here, but I can't seem to figure out how to make this work.

I have a p:dialog which contains a text field, a select one menu, an auto complete, an editor, and a fileupload object. The idea is that the user will enter some information into the fields, optionally attach some files to the fileupload and then press the submit button on the dialog which will call my backing bean, do some processing and handle getting the files where they need to go. I would like to use the advanced file uploader so that users can attach multiple files. When users press the submit button, all of the data is properly submitted except for the fileuploader. The upload listener is never fired.

I did some searching online and found some referenced to possibly being able to trigger the upload with a call to wigdetVar.upload(), but that just throws a javascript error, and further searching suggests that functionality may no longer be available.

So the question is, how can I submit the files along with the rest of the form from the submit button? Code for the dialog follows.

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="newthreaddialog" modal="true" header="New Thread for #{collaborationBacking.patientName}" dynamic="true"
                       resizeable="false">
              <div class="whitebox">
                 <h:form id="newthreadform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <p:panelGrid>
                       <p:row>   
                          <p:column>
                             <p:messages/>
                             <h:outputLabel for="threadtitle" value="Thread Title: "/>
                             <p:inputText id="threadtitle" label="Thread Title" value="#{newCollabThreadBacking.title}" required="true"/>
                          </p:column>
                          <p:column>
                             <h:outputLabel for="threadtype" value="Type: "/>
                             <h:selectOneMenu id="threadtype" label="Thread Type" value="#{newCollabThreadBacking.type}">
                                <f:selectItems value="#{newCollabThreadBacking.typeList}"/>
                             </h:selectOneMenu>
                          </p:column>
                       </p:row>

                       <p:row>
                          <p:column colspan="2">
                             <h:outputLabel for="addressedTo" value="To: "/>
                             <p:autoComplete id="addressedTo" value="#{newCollabThreadBacking.addressedTo}"
                                                   completeMethod="#{newCollabThreadBacking.completeAddress}"
                                                   var="practice"
                                                   itemValue="#{practice}"
                                                   itemLabel="#{practice.name}"
                                                   converter="practiceConverter"
                                                   forceSelection="true"/>
                          </p:column>
                       </p:row>


                       <p:row>
                          <p:column colspan="2">
                             <p:editor value="#{newCollabThreadBacking.content}" label="Message Content" required="true"/>
                          </p:column>
                       </p:row>

                       <p:row>
                          <p:column colspan="2">
                             <p:fileUpload widgetVar="uploader" fileUploadListener="#{newCollabThreadBacking.fileUpload}"/>
                          </p:column>
                       </p:row>

                       <p:row>
                          <p:column colspan="2">
                             <span class="submit">
                                <p:commandButton id="submitthread" value="Submit" action="#{newCollabThreadBacking.saveThread}"
                                                          oncomplete="newThreadResult(xhr, status, args)"
                                                          onclick="uploader.upload();"
                                                          process="@form" update="@form"/>
                             </span>
                          </p:column>
                       </p:row>                              
                    </p:panelGrid>
                 </h:form>
              </div>

              <p:ajax event="close" listener="#{collaborationBacking.reloadThreads}" update="threadtable newthreadform"/>
           </p:dialog> <!-- newthreaddialog -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a file upload filter? you need to add a fileUpload filter in the web.xml file to be able to upload files to the server. Try add the following to your web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Yes, I did add that. And the upload listener is called if I click the upload button, but not if the form is submitted.

Comment: @moneyt Can I see your backing bean code? Try to change the scope

Comment: Sorry, I've sense dropped that set of code. To mostly solve the issue, I had the file uploader auto upload to a temporary location, and then had the form submission handle moving the temporary files to their permanent home. I don't think I have a copy of that code in version control anywhere. Thanks for your help though.